# Pivot/Transpose rows into columns efficiently with multiple columns

Tags: sql, pivot, sql-server-2016

Let's say I have data that looks liek this:

```
  Table
  Num1       Type1       Code       Group      DA        Account      Value
  1X2        GG          XX1        INTS       1         123          75.00
  1X2        GG          XX1        INTS       1         234          100.00
```

What's I'm trying to do is Pivot the data so it looks like this:

```
  Num1       Type1       Code       Group      DA      123        234
  1X2        GG          XX1        INTS       1       75.00      100.00
```

I'm not really sure how something like this can be accomplished with PIVOT, but I did try the below approach:

```
 Select Num1, 
        Type1, 
        Code, 
        Group, 
        DA, 
        '123' = (Select Value from Table t2 where t1.num1 = t2.num1 and Account = 123 ),
        '234' = (Select Value from Table t2 where t1.num1 = t2.num1 and Account = 234 )
 From Table t1
```

However the error I'm getting is: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

In that case I added "Top 1" to each subquery:

```
Select Num1, 
        Type1, 
        Code, 
        Group, 
        DA, 
        '123' = (Select TOP 1 Value from Table t2 where t1.num1 = t2.num1 and Account = 123 ),
        '234' = (Select TOP 1 Value from Table t2 where t1.num1 = t2.num1 and Account = 234 )
 From Table t1
```

However, even though the query now returns two rows with AMOUNTS for each Account, I'm not fully understanding the purpose of TOP 1, but basically now the data looks like this:

```
 Num1       Type1       Code       Group      DA        123        234
  1X2        GG          XX1        INTS       1        NULL       100.00 
  1X2        GG          XX1        INTS       1        75.00      NULL
```

And I guess that's not bad, because I can do a `MAX(123)` and `MAX(234)` with `GROUP BY` on all the other columns, and end up with 1 row.

Is there a better approach to this? Can this be achieved with PIVOT?